How does proprietary library's copyright/EULA impact on dependent program source code's copyright/license? (not program binary)
(This question is solely about the license/copyright of source code, not about the combined program/package.)
How does a library's copyright carry over to dependent source code?
Let a program-A be written from ground up while using proprietary lib-B, where program-A source contains calls to lib-B's APIs and maybe also includes lib-B's header files.
Can the author of program-A redistribute the source code under any license?
Case A
If lib-B headers or sources are publicly visible, but covered by random proprietary license.
Case B
If lib-B headers or sources are not publicly visible.
Case C
If lib-B headers or sources are gated behind convoluted terms like Unreal Engine EULA. (section 6-c)
Unreal EULA 6-c is vague, but the actual effect (to source code) is unclear to me.

Can program-A author release source code under GPLv3?
Can other people compile and use program-A without breaking lib-B's EULA?
Can other people modify and redistribute program-A sources under GPLv3?
For 2/3, I think people can claim that they conform to lib-B's EULA andy violate program-A's GPL.

Case D
If lib-B explicitly states something like "user cannot publish dependent code under certain license" or "user cannot opensource or release dependent code", is it legally valid?
I was aware of Oracle vs Google case, but I don't know if it is relevant here.

This is a definitive "maybe" for all sub-questions. This will depend a lot on the exact terms of the proprietary license contract. This is clearest in your scenario D: yes, the contracts you enter can impose conditions that do not depend on whether program A is a derivative work. The contract could also stipulate that you may only release on Tuesdays, and only after doing 10 pushups. Contracts may contain any terms as long as they're not unconsciable or preempted by specific laws.

For 6-C.  I think what they're saying is their license is in conflict with GPL, so you'd really be violating the GPL license if you also used Ureal engine code.  They specify DLLs because those are binary distributions and just calling those (or executables) without including the source code may get around your responsibility to obey the GPL license.  So the calling program does not inherit the called binary's source license.  (API or com control or DLL)

Apache did try to claim that Google needed to pay to use their APIs however they did ultimately lose the case.   It was a pretty fine line that Google walked there... taking the language and compiling it for their own run-time that included plenty of Java SE APIs but no source code per say.

If this question is unsuitable here, perhaps [opensource.se] may be a better place to ask?

@TobySpeight, as the question does not involve open-source licenses, it is not suitable for the site you suggest.

@Bart, are you sure?  Author wants to distribute code using GPLv3, which I assumed to mean GNU General Public License (confirmed with the [tag:gpl] tag).  That certainly is open-source, as far as I'm aware.

@TobySpeight, GPLv3 is open-source, but that license is only mentioned in case C and possibly only because the Unreal EULA calls out that license. Nowhere else in the question do I see a desire to use an open-source license.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
